# How to build a reverse traceability matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with traceability matrix between requirements and specifications, and need to be able to produce a reverse traceability, i.e. list all the requirements of each specifications.
For example:

list of specifications for each requirement

[image: list of specifications for each requirement]

I would like to produce something like:
List of requirements for each specification

[image: List of requirements for each specification]

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Unpivot the `spec` columns, then group by Spec. I suggest you use Power Query, although VBA can do this also.  Formulas will be difficult and complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that using Power Query.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table name in next line to the actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table34"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Type})),

//Unpivot columns other than the 'REQ' column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Req"}, "Attribute", "spec"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Group by 'spec'
//  then generate a semicolon delimited list for `Req's`
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"spec"}, {
        {"Req", each Text.Combine([Req],";")}
        }),

//Generate listof column names for the Table.SplitColumn function
    maxCols =  List.Accumulate(#"Grouped Rows"[Req],
                    0, 
                    (state, current)=> 
                        let 
                            x =List.Count(Text.PositionOf(current,";",Occurrence.All)) + 1
                        in 
                            if x > state then x else state),
    colNamesList = List.Transform({1..maxCols}, each "Req " & Number.ToText(_)),

//sort by 'spec'
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"spec", Order.Ascending}}),

//Split by semicolon
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Req", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),colNamesList),

//set data types
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", 
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Split Column by Delimiter"), each {_, Text.Type}))
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]